# How to filter convert a date field into a date to extract the current month in SQLite db using func.strftime() in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, datetime, flask, sqlalchemy, func

I want to know the subscribed events (events that I am following) that took place in current month. This is irrespective of whether they took place 5 years ago, or a year ago, so long as they took place in the current month. I am convinced by problem emanates from `Event.event_date`. How do I convert this field into a date the `strftime()` can then extract the the month from it using `'%m'` and then compare it to the current month.

However, the query gives no events that took place in the current month, yet I have events that indeed took place in April (the current month). The current month is to be automated, which I have successfully accomplished through `datetime.today().strftime('%m')`. Then I want to compare this month with all events that took place in the same month. Here is the full query code:

```
monthly_events = current_user.followed_events().filter(Event.event_date < datetime.today().date()).filter(func.strftime('%m', Event.event_date == datetime.today().strftime('%m'))).order_by(Event.timestamp.desc())
```

By breaking the query into sections, I was able to know where the problem is.
The section of the query: `current_user.followed_events().filter(Event.event_date < datetime.today().date())` gives all events that have passed (yesterday and beyond). This part works correctly.

The section: `current_user.followed_events().filter(Event.event_date < datetime.today().date()).order_by(Event.timestamp.desc())` arranges these pasts events in descending order and this section works correctly, as well.

However, the part with problem is: `.filter(func.strftime('%m', Event.event_date == datetime.today().strftime('%m')))` where the aim is to filter out events that took place in the current month, irrespective of the year they took place.

Note that I have imported the following modules `from sqlalchemy import func` and `from datetime import datetime` at the top of the `routes.py`.

The `event_date` field in the `models.py` is stored as a `db.DateTime` with a `default = datetime.utcnow`. I am using `Flask`, with `SQLite` db, but will change it to `Postgresql` later.

I hope the information is enough, otherwise let me know if additional information is needed.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a little more research, I found the answer by using the extract object in `sqlalchemy`. The working query looks is:

```
from sqlalchemy import extract 

#....
monthly_events = current_user.followed_events().filter(Event.event_date < datetime.today().date()).filter(extract('month', Event.event_date) == datetime.today().month)).order_by(Event.timestamp.desc())
#...
```